# Как построить на графике тренд по временному ряду или как-то его усреднить?

Tags: r, rstudio

Имеется временной ряд и его отображение, но оно очень "грязное", подскажите пожалуйста как построить график тренда что ли или изменить этот, для того, чтобы анализ был удобнее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth()`

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Тип сглаживания можно выбирать.